# Why do I get unauthorized despite of valid Token?

Tags: c#, jwt, webapi

The token is generated through this method:

```
private string GenerateJwtToken(User user)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var base64Key = _configuration["Jwt:Secret"];

    try
    {
        var key = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Key);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Issuer = _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            Audience = _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(
                new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
                    new Claim("UserId", user.ID.ToString())
                }
            ),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(14),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature
            )
        };

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"error converting Base64 string: {ex.Message}");
        return null;
    }
}
```

I checked on jwt.io and it says the token generated is valid.

When I use thunderclient to my /user endpoint to get the user by passing the JWT token in the header then I get Status: 401 Unauthorized.

Here is my post method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserDTO>> GetUserDTO()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I GET USER");
    try
    {
        var jwt = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]
                .ToString()
                .Replace("Bearer ", string.Empty);

        Console.WriteLine(jwt);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jwt))
        {
            return BadRequest("JWT token is missing.");
        }
        var loggedInUser = _userService.GetByJWT(jwt);

        if (loggedInUser == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Failed to get user.");
        }

        return Ok(loggedInUser.FirstName);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, e.Message);
    }
}
```

When I remove `[Authorize]` then it works and it can resolve the id from the JWT bearer.

In `program.cs` I have my authorize schema and tried to change it and see if it's something wrong with my issuer or audience? I set my issuer value as my application name and the audience value as API since it's the API that will use it. Is that correct? Here is the schema:

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Secret"])
            ),
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"]
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

Why do I get unauthorized?

***EDITED***
Here is how I have tried setting the header / authorizarion

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the request's `Authorization` header in correct format? Does the Authorization header in your  actual request blocked by [Authorize] starts with `Bearer ...`?

Comment: Hi,@Angelina, could you show how you set the header?

Comment: `var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();` <-- When you do this, it means you're **not** using the configuration set in `.AddJwtBearer`. Generally speaking, when you're using a DI system, if you ever find yourself using the `new` operator, it probably means you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Secret"])` <-- Doing this tells me that your key is comprised of human-readable text, which means you have a limited _keyspace_ (because you won't be using the full range of `0x00-0xFF` for each byte) - instead consider using JSON strings to hold Base16 or Base64 values, which you then decode into full-ranged bytes, which will be far more resistant to brute-force searches - or at least use [a key-derivation-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function).

Comment: I added pictures on how I have tried sending the jwt in the request :)

Comment: I'm asking because I can't see the entire contents of the program.cs file. Did you define "app.UseAuthentication();" in program.cs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use two different keys, see the following lines:

```cs
var key = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Key); //used to generate a jwt

IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Secret"])
            ) // used to check a jwt
```

Basically `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` and `Convert.FromBase64String(base64Key)` don't return the same `byte[]` for the same string

Change the line to the following in your `.AddJwtBearer` method call

```
IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Convert.FromBase64String(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Secret"])
            ) // used to check a jwt
```

Comment: But shouldn't it be the same since base64key is the Jwt Secret key?

 var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var base64Key = _configuration["Jwt:Secret"];

Comment: oh do you mean I should use the same instance of SymmetricSecurityKey?

Comment: This was the solution!! Thank you so much :D It works!!